# Date format parse exception - “EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy”

Tags: date, sql-server-2012, date-format, simpledateformat

i got date like this in a csv file **Sun Sep 02 05:00:00 UTC 2012**. How do i convert this string in yyyy/mm/dd format in sql server to get output like this:- **2012/09/02**.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server comes with the following data types for storing a date or a date/time value in the database:

```
  DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), SYSDATETIME(), 111) AS [YYYY/MM/DD]
```

see this [date format table](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx)

Comment: but is there any way to get only date 2012/09/02 out of Sun Sep 02 05:00:00 UTC 2012

Comment: @user3812365 huh? what do you mean? can you post your query?

Comment: i got date in a csv file & want to save that date in yyyy/mm/dd format.please read my question...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old but I had a similar problem and this came up first in a search.

So if it may help others, my solution is this:

> try_parse(left([Date Field], 11) + right([Date Field], 4) +
> substring([Date Field], 11, 9) as datetime)

This solution rearranges the text and drops the time zone in a manner that allows SQL Server to convert to datetime. Not very elegant but gets the job done.